# Catch warnings in multithreaded code without treating them as errors

Tags: python, multithreading, warnings

I want to do something like:

```
def my_function_running_in_a_thread_pool():
    # stuff

    try:
        # something that might raise a UserWarning
        raise UserWarning
    except UserWarning as e:
        print(e)

    # more stuff
```

Except that both "stuff" and "more stuff rely on the warnings not raising exceptions, and the function runs in a threadpool so while one cycle might be at the try/except block, another at the same time might be at the "more stuff" step.

I cannot use warnings.filterwarnings or warnings.catch_warnings because they're not thread-safe.

How can I do this?

A lock is not a great idea because I might need to put expensive and time-consuming functions inside the try/except block.